# Print PDF file shows up as garbage

Tags: printing, pdf

I'm trying to print several PDF files exported from Google Docs. When I open them in Document Viewer, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select my printer, it spews out several pages of garbage which appear to be the raw code of the file (It starts with `%PDF`).

What's the problem here? Is there any fix, or at least a workaround?